# Map values to higher dimension with Numpy

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I'm trying to apply a color map to a two dimensional gray-scale image in Numpy (the image is loaded/generated by OpenCV).

I have a 256 entries long list with RGB values, which is my colormap:

```
cMap = [np.array([0, 0, 0], dtype=np.uint8),
        np.array([0, 1, 1], dtype=np.uint8),
        np.array([0, 0, 4], dtype=np.uint8),
        np.array([0, 0, 6], dtype=np.uint8),
        np.array([0, 1, 9], dtype=np.uint8),
        np.array([ 0,  0, 12], dtype=np.uint8),
        # Many more entries here
       ]
```

When I input a gray scale image (shape `(y,x,1)`), I would like to output a color image (shape `(y,x,3)`), where the gray scale value for each input pixel is used as an index in `cMap` to find the appropriate color for the output pixel. My feeble attempt so far (inspired by [Fast replacement of values in a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403973/fast-replacement-of-values-in-a-numpy-array)) looks like this:

```
colorImg = np.zeros(img.shape[:2] + (3,), dtype=np.uint8)

for k, v in enumerate(cMap):
    colorImg[img==k] = v
```

This gives me the error `ValueError: array is not broadcastable to correct shape`. I think I have narrowed the problem down: The slicing I do results in a 1D boolean array with an entry for each entry in `img`. `colorImg`, however has three times more entries than `img`, so the boolean array won't be long enough.

I have tried all kinds of reshaping and other slicings, but I'm pretty stuck now. I'm sure there is an elegant way to solve this :-)

Comment: Try doing `cMap = np.asarray(cMap); colorImg = cMap[img[..., 0]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are looking for is [`numpy.take()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html). The only tricky bit is to specify `axis = 0` so that the returned image has the correct number of channels.

```
colorImg = np.take(np.asarray(cMap), img, axis = 0)
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you. I had to reshape the result, but other than that, it worked perfectly: `colorImg = np.take(np.asarray(cMap), img, axis = 0).reshape(img.shape[:2] + (3,))`