# Find and replace multiple values in python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I want to find and replace multiple values in an 1D array / list with new ones.

In example for a list

```
a=[2, 3, 2, 5, 4, 4, 1, 2]
```

I would like to replace

```
val_old=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

with

```
val_new=[2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
```

Therefore the new array is:

```
a_new=[3, 4, 3, 1, 5, 5, 2, 3]
```

What is the fastest way to do this (for very large lists, i.e. with 50000 values to find and replace)?

**Comment** **of** **the** **anwsers**

Thank you to all for a quick response! I checked the proposed solutions with the following:

```
N = 10**4
N_val = 0.5*N
a = np.random.randint(0, N_val, size=N)
val_old = np.arange(N_val, dtype=np.int)
val_new = np.arange(N_val, dtype=np.int)
np.random.shuffle(val_new)

a1 = list(a)
val_old1 = list(val_old)
val_new1 = list(val_new)

def Ashwini_Chaudhary(a, val_old, val_new):
    arr = np.empty(a.max()+1, dtype=val_new.dtype)
    arr[val_old] = val_new
    return arr[a]

def EdChum(a, val_old, val_new):
    df = pd.Series(a, dtype=val_new.dtype)
    d = dict(zip(val_old, val_new))
    return df.map(d).values   

def xxyzzy(a, val_old, val_new):
    return [val_new[val_old.index(x)] for x in a]

def Shashank_and_Hackaholic(a, val_old, val_new):
    d = dict(zip(val_old, val_new))
    return [d.get(e, e) for e in a]

def itzmeontv(a, val_old, val_new):
    return [val_new[val_old.index(i)] if i in val_old else i for i in a]

def swenzel(a, val_old, val_new):
    return val_new[np.searchsorted(val_old,a)]

def Divakar(a, val_old, val_new):
    C,R = np.where(a[:,np.newaxis] == val_old[np.newaxis,:])
    a[C] = val_new[R]
    return a
```

The results:

```
%timeit -n100 Ashwini_Chaudhary(a, val_old, val_new)
100 loops, best of 3: 77.6 µs per loop

%timeit -n100 swenzel(a, val_old, val_new)
100 loops, best of 3: 703 µs per loop

%timeit -n100 Shashank_and_Hackaholic(a1, val_old1, val_new1)
100 loops, best of 3: 1.7 ms per loop

%timeit -n100 EdChum(a, val_old, val_new)
100 loops, best of 3: 17.6 ms per loop

%timeit -n10 Divakar(a, val_old, val_new)
10 loops, best of 3: 209 ms per loop

%timeit -n10 xxyzzy(a1, val_old1, val_new1)
10 loops, best of 3: 429 ms per loop

%timeit -n10 itzmeontv(a1, val_old1, val_new1)
10 loops, best of 3: 847 ms per loop
```

The relative difference in performance increases with biger `N` , i.e. if `N=10**7`, then the result by Ashwini_Chaudhary takes `207 ms` and the result by swenzel `6.89 s`.

Comment: Here is pretty much the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403973/fast-replacement-of-values-in-a-numpy-array
In case one needs a generic non-integer solution it's really interesting that for a large number of replacements *Shashank*'s solution is the fastest. For a low number of replacements the numpy solution of the accepted answer in the linked question is the best. It's great how fast python dictionaries and list comprehensions are.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> arr = np.empty(a.max() + 1, dtype=val_new.dtype)
>>> arr[val_old] = val_new
>>> arr[a]
array([3, 4, 3, 1, 5, 5, 2, 3])
```

Comment: Was also my first attempt... gets a bit tricky if `a` contains negative numbers.

Comment: For negative number calculate an additional offset: `offset=max(-a.min(), 0) ; arr = np.empty(a.max() + 1 + offset, dtype=val_new.dtype); arr[val_old + offset] = val_new; a_new = arr[a + offset] `

Answer (score 4):

In vanilla Python, without the speed of `numpy` or `pandas`, this is one way:

```
a = [2, 3, 2, 5, 4, 4, 1, 2]
val_old = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
val_new = [2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
expected_a_new = [3, 4, 3, 1, 5, 5, 2, 3]
d = dict(zip(val_old, val_new))
a_new = [d.get(e, e) for e in a]
print a_new # [3, 4, 3, 1, 5, 5, 2, 3]
print a_new == expected_a_new # True
```

The *average* time complexity for this algorithm is `O(M + N)` where `M` is the length of your "translation list" and `N` is the length of list `a`.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your `val_old` array is sorted (which is the case here, but if later on it's not, then don't forget to sort `val_new` along with it!), you can use `numpy.searchsorted` and then access `val_new` with the results.
**This does not work if a number has no mapping, you will have to provide 1to1 mappings in that case.**

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.array([2, 3, 2, 5, 4, 4, 1, 2])

In [3]: old_val = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

In [4]: new_val = np.array([2, 3, 4, 5, 1])

In [5]: a_new = np.array([3, 4, 3, 1, 5, 5, 2, 3])

In [6]: i = np.searchsorted(old_val,a)

In [7]: a_replaced = new_val[i]

In [8]: all(a_replaced == a_new)
Out[8]: True
```

50k numbers? No problem!

```
In [23]: def timed():
    t0 = time.time()
    i = np.searchsorted(old_val, a)
    a_replaced = new_val[i]
    t1 = time.time()
    print('%s Seconds'%(t1-t0))
   ....: 

In [24]: a = np.random.choice(old_val, 50000)

In [25]: timed()
0.00288081169128 Seconds
```

500k? You won't notice the difference!

```
In [26]: a = np.random.choice(old_val, 500000)

In [27]: timed()
0.019248008728 Seconds
```

Answer (score 2):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author) provides an elegant and efficient vectorized solution to this type of problem:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
remapped_a = npi.remap(a, val_old, val_new)
```

The method implemented is based on searchsorted like that of swenzel and should have similar good performance, but more general. For instance, the items of the array do not need to be ints, but can be any type, even nd-subarrays themselves.

If all values in 'a' are expected to be present in 'val_old', you can set the optional 'missing' kwarg to 'raise' (default is 'ignore'). Performance will be slightly better, and you will get a KeyError if that assumption is not satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your expected output, works even if `elements` not in `value_old`.

```
>>>[val_new[val_old.index(i)] if i in val_old else i for i in a]
[3, 4, 3, 1, 5, 5, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

For `numpy arrays`, this could be one approach -

```
%// Find row and column IDs for matches between "a" and "val_old"
C,R = np.where(a[:,np.newaxis] == val_old[np.newaxis,:])

%// Index into "a" with the column indices and 
%// set those to "val_new" elements indexed by "R"
a[C] = val_new[R]
```

---

**Sample run and timing**

For inputs:

```
a = np.random.randint(10000,size=(100000))
val_old = np.random.randint(10000,size=(1000))
val_new = np.random.randint(10000,size=(1000))
```

Runtimes at each code line were -

```
%timeit C,R = np.where(a[:,np.newaxis] == val_old[np.newaxis,:])
1 loops, best of 3: 292 ms per loop

%timeit a[C] = val_new[R]
10000 loops, best of 3: 43 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace values in a list using two other lists as key:value pairs there are several approaches.  All of them use "list compression".

Using list.index():

```
a=[2, 3, 2, 5, 4, 4, 1, 2]
val_old=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
val_new=[2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
a_new=[val_new[val_old.index(x)] for x in a]
```

Using your special case:

```
a=[2, 3, 2, 5, 4, 4, 1, 2]
a_new=[x % 5 + 1 for x in a]
```

Comment: The 'index' approach will work, but it will be slower than the `dict` approach for hashable items.

Answer (score 0):

I tried like this:

```
>>> val_old=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> val_new=[2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
>>> a=[2, 3, 2, 5, 4, 4, 1, 2]
>>> my_dict = dict(zip(val_old, val_new))
>>> [my_dict.get(x,x) for x in a]
[3, 4, 3, 1, 5, 5, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

In pandas I would create a dict from the 2 lists and then call `map` which will perform a lookup and replace the values:

```
In [6]:

df = pd.Series([2, 3, 2, 5, 4, 4, 1, 2])
df
Out[6]:
0    2
1    3
2    2
3    5
4    4
5    4
6    1
7    2
dtype: int64
In [7]:

val_old=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
val_new=[2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
d = dict(zip(val_old,val_new ))
d
Out[7]:
{1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 1}
In [9]:

df.map(d)

Out[9]:
0    3
1    4
2    3
3    1
4    5
5    5
6    2
7    3
dtype: int64
```

For a 80000 element series this takes 3.4ms:

```
In [14]:

%timeit df.map(d)

100 loops, best of 3: 3.4 ms per loop
```

This is a vectorised approach and will scale much better than any iteration based method

Comment: This approach isn't vectorized, `map` uses iteration.  For long lists, it is a bit faster doing the `map`, but the time necessary to construct the `Series` means the iteration-based approach ends up being faster overall.

Answer (score 0):

```
list(map(lambda x:val_new[val_old.index(x)], a))
```