# Replace values from (m,n,3) array with conditions from (m,n,1) array

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have the following array:

```py
a = np.random.randint(5, size=(2000, 2000, 1))
a = np.repeat(a, 3, axis=2) # Using this method to have a (m,n,3) array with the same values
```

and the next arrays:

```py
val_old = np.array([[0,  0,   0],  [3,  3,  3]])
val_new = np.array([[12, 125, 13], [78, 78, 0]])
```

What I want to do is to replace the values from the array `a` with the values specified in the array `val_new`. So, all `[0,0,0]` arrays would become `[12,125,13]` and all `[3,3,3]` would become `[78, 78, 0]`.

I can't find an efficient way to do this... I tried to adapt [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29407945/find-and-replace-multiple-values-in-python) but it's only for 1-d arrays...

Does anyone know a fast way/method to replace these values ?

Comment: Would all three values in each of the row in `val_old` be the same? Also, are all rows from `val_old` guaranteed to be in `a`? And can we use `a = np.random.randint(5, size=(2000, 2000, 1))` as the starting point, that is since the repeated version would have the values repeated anyway, so start off with the original "2D" version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a "map" for each integer, you can use a (2000, 2000) index on a (5,) array to broadcast to a (2000,2000, 5) array. example:

```
val_new = np.array([[12, 125, 13], [0,0,0], [1,3,3], [78, 78, 0]])  #0, 1, 2, 3
a = np.random.randint(4,size=(4,5))

val_new[a]  # (4,5,3) shaped array

>>array([[[  0,   0,   0],
    [ 78,  78,   0],
    [ 78,  78,   0],
    [ 12, 125,  13],
    [  0,   0,   0]],
....
   [[ 12, 125,  13],
    [ 12, 125,  13],
    [  0,   0,   0],
    [ 12, 125,  13],
    [  0,   0,   0]]])
```