# How can I convert a numpy array containing a list of strings into an array containing a list of zeros and ones?

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn, data-science, bayesian

Right now I have this numpy array containing predictions of whether an email is *'spam'* or *'ham'*. So basically the result of a spam predicting model. I want to compare to a an array containing the classes of test set used. When I use the `MultinominalNB.score()` method on them, I get an error because it is meant to compare float values not strings.

So how can I change these two arrays into float values based on whether the list entry was *'spam'* or *'ham'*? And better still, is there another better method to quantitatively measure the quality of the model?

Comment: Can you give some example data?

Comment: array(['ham', 'spam', 'ham', 'spam', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham',
       'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham',
       'ham', 'spam', 'ham', 'ham', 'spam', 'ham', 'ham', 'spam', 'ham',
       'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham'....], dtype=object) That is the test classes for instance, and the is the predictions array(['ham', 'spam', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham',
       'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham',
       'ham', 'spam', 'ham', 'ham', 'spam'....], dtype='<U4')

Comment: What about `a == 'ham'`?

Comment: I tried to iteratively change them using a for a loop as follows:
for c, x in test_classes:
if x == 'ham':
test_classes[c] = 0, but I get a ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: @AhmedSamir Please edit your question when you have additional information. People tend to ignore comments and you can't format code properly in  a comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fast replacement of values in a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403973/fast-replacement-of-values-in-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have obtained the `y_true` and `y_predicted` then use this:

```
import numpy as np


y_test = np.array(['ham', 'spam', 'ham', 'spam', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 
                   'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 
                   'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'spam','ham', 'ham', 'spam'], dtype=object)

y_predicted = np.array(['ham', 'spam', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham',
                        'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 
                        'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'spam','ham', 'ham', 'spam'], dtype=object)

y_test[y_test == 'ham']=0
y_test[y_test == 'spam']=1

y_predicted[y_predicted == 'ham']=0
y_predicted[y_predicted == 'spam']=1
```

**Results:**

```
print(y_test=
#array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], dtype=object)

print(y_predicted)
#array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], dtype=object)
```