# Assign value to string in np array, convert to int, and calculate weighted average

Tags: python, numpy

I'm wondering if you can me figure out how to assign value to string in `np array`, and convert to `int`, then calculate weighted average. For example,

```
test_np = array(['HARD', 'HARD', 'EASY', 'MODERATE', 'MODERATE', 'EASY', 'MODERATE', 'MODERATE', 'EASY', 'MODERATE', 'MODERATE', 'HARD', 'EASY'])
```

where `'HARD'=10`, `'MODERATE'=5`, and `'EASY'=1` so the results should be something like this so I can calculate weighted average with `np.average()`

```
test_np = array([10, 10, 1, 5, 5, 1, 5, 5, 1, 5, 5, 10, 1])
```

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Use `HARD`,`EASY` and `MODERATE` as variables instead of strings.

Comment: 'HARD', 'EASY', 'MODERATE' are given strings from the table so I'm looking for way to convert them to numbers so that I can make further calculation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fast replacement of values in a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403973/fast-replacement-of-values-in-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your test_np to a pandas series, and use map to convert your strings to integers. Then you could take the average of that series

Input:

```
df = pd.Series(test_np)
test_dict = { 'HARD':10, 'MODERATE':5,'EASY':1}
df = df.map(test_dict)
df.mean()
```

Output for df:

```
0     10
1     10
2      1
3      5
4      5
5      1
6      5
7      5
8      1
9      5
10     5
11    10
12     1
dtype: int64
```

Output for average:

```
4.923076923076923
```

Comment: No.. just do `Series`

Answer (score 0):

A simple dictionary with list comprehension solution:

```
In [45]: test_np = np.array(['HARD', 'HARD', 'EASY', 'MODERATE', 'MODERATE', 'EA
    ...: SY', 'MODERATE', 'MODERATE', 'EASY', 'MODERATE', 'MODERATE', 'HARD', 'E
    ...: ASY'])
In [46]: 
In [46]: adict = {'HARD':10, 'MODERATE':5, 'EASY':1}
In [47]: np.array([adict[i] for i in test_np])
Out[47]: array([10, 10,  1,  5,  5,  1,  5,  5,  1,  5,  5, 10,  1])
```