# Find and replace specific values within 2D array

Tags: python, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I have a large 2D array, `array`, with each entry being a large array of numbers
:

```
array = [
            [1, 0, 3, ...],
            [5, 4, 1, ...],
            [1, 2, 3, ...],
            ...
        ]
```

All the numbers in the 2D array are from 0-5 and I have to somehow find and replace specific numbers, like, for example, all occurrences of the number `3` and replace it with `5`.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a **[mcve]**?

Comment: As you say 'specific numbers' is it correct that you are searching for more than 1 number? Do you know what these numbers are beforehand?

Comment: Yes, the only numbers in the arrays are from 0-5, so i have to replace 1 with -5, 2 with -3, 3 with 1, 4 with 3 and 5 with 5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fast replacement of values in a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403973/fast-replacement-of-values-in-a-numpy-array)

Comment: @jojo, Above is a **perfect** dup of this question. I suggest you post your answer there..

Comment: This question doesn't seem unclear to me.

Answer (score 5):

This can be **done with list comprehension** in a simple one-liner.

Say you have a list of lists:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

and you want to replace all occurrences of `2` with `4`:

```
[[_el if _el != 2 else 4 for _el in _ar] for _ar in a]
```

Another option is to use **numpy's [`where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) function**. From the docstring:

> where(condition, [x, y])
>
> Return elements, either from `x` or `y`, depending on `condition`.

So, in your case (say you'd like again to replace all `2` with `4`):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
   [1, 2, 3],
   [1, 2, 3]])

np.where(a==2, 4, a)
```

If you want to replace several values in one go, you could do something like this:
Say you'd like to replace `1` with `3` and `3` with `5`:

```
ix=np.isin(array, [1,3])
vc=np.vectorize(lambda x: 3 if x == 1 else 5)
np.where(ix, vc(array), array)
```

If you have more than 2 values to replace, say you want to map the list `[1,3,5]` to `[3, 5, -3]`, then you can define a simple function like:

```
old_vals = [1,3,5]
new_vals = [3, 5, -3]
def switch_val(x):
    return new_vals[old_vals.index(x)] if x in old_vals else x
```

and so:

```
vc=np.vectorize(switch_val)
vc(array)
```

where we [vectorized](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) the function.

*Hope that helped and happy coding!*

Comment: Just curious, given the OP wants to replace multiple values, I guess the most pythonic approach would be to use np.where multiple times...? Rather than using a bunch of conditions and/or elifs?

Comment: @NathanThomas sorry for the hick-hack. I added it to the answer. :)

Comment: I was just curious, but it turned out to be pretty elegant. It's good to see the full working example for future use!

Comment: @NathanThomas you are very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(array)):
    for j in range(len(array[i])):
        if array[i][j] == value_you_are_looking_for:
            array[i][j] = new_value
```

This should work

Comment: Thanks, i tried this form but it didn't work for some reason it just printed the exact same array                                                                                                              
 for i in range(len(new_set)):
    for j in range(len(new_set[i])):
        if new_set[i][j] == 1:
            new_set[i][j] = -5
print(new_set)

Answer (score 0):

For a single value, given you have an array called Arr, such that:

```
Arr = np.array([[1,2,3],
                [1,2,3],
                [1,2,3]])
```

Then:

```
mask = Arr == 2
```

gives:

```
mask = np.array([[False,True,False],
                [False,True,False],
                [False,True,False]])
```

finally, replacing 2 with 4:

```
newArr[mask] = 4
```

gives:

```
Arr = np.array([[1,4,3],
                [1,4,3],
                [1,4,3]])
```