# How to use Numpy to replace values in a matrix with a color e.g.[0,255,0]

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix which only contains 0 or 1.
I also have a list of colors e.g. the below

```
class_colors = [[0,0,0], [0,255,0]]
m = np.random.random_integers(0,1,(5,5))
```

e.g. the `m` looks like:

```
0,1,0,1
0,1,0,1
0,1,0,1
```

How can I replace the 1-values in `m` with the `class_colors[1]` and
0-values in `m` with `class_colors[0]` , so the `m` will look something like:

```
[0,0,0], [0,255,0],[0,0,0], [0,255,0]
[0,0,0], [0,255,0],[0,0,0], [0,255,0]
[0,0,0], [0,255,0],[0,0,0], [0,255,0]
```

I used to be able to do so with `np.argmax()` and `np.take()` but it requires the `m` looks like `[class_num,w,h]` and then I can do argmax with `axis=0`.

I know I could do it with for loop, but is there any better and faster approach to do this?

Comment: Have you searched for the problem? What did you find?

Comment: @Trilarion searched and found this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55949809/efficiently-replace-elements-in-array-based-on-dictionary-numpy-python and many others but not able to apply those methods....

Comment: Please include your search results in the question text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it what you expect:

```
>>> c[m]
array([[[  0,   0,   0],
        [  0, 255,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0, 255,   0]],

       [[  0,   0,   0],
        [  0, 255,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0, 255,   0]]])

>>> c  # c = np.array(class_colors)
array([[  0,   0,   0],
       [  0, 255,   0]])

>>> m  # m = np.random.randint(0, 2, (2, 4))
array([[0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

By extension:

```
class_colors = [[0,0,0], [0,255,0], [255,0,0], [0,0,255]]
c = np.array(class_colors)
m = np.random.randint(0, 4, (2, 4))
# m <- array([[2, 1, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1, 0]])
```

```
>>> c[m]
array([[[255,   0,   0],
        [  0, 255,   0],
        [  0, 255,   0],
        [  0,   0, 255]],

       [[255,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0, 255],
        [  0, 255,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0]]])
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation and extension example. :)

Answer (score 2):

Not surprisingly the intuitive way works (using advanced indexing):

```
class_colors = np.array([[0,0,0], [0,255,0]])
m = np.array([0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]).reshape((3,4))
class_colors[m]
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't know I could do it in this way. good learn.