# Replace values in 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have following 2D numpay array:

```
matrix = np.array([
    [ 0,  1,  4,  3],
    [ 1,  2,  5,  4],
    [ 3,  4,  7,  6],
    [ 4,  5,  8,  7],
    [ 2, 10, 13,  5],
    [10, 11, 14, 13],
    [ 5, 13, 16,  8],
    [13, 14, 17, 16],
    [18, 19, 22, 21],
    [19, 11, 10, 22],
    [21, 22,  1,  0],
    [22, 10,  2,  1]])
```

I have another array which carries the values that I want to replace inside matrix.

```
substitutes = np.array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8, 10, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22])
```

Find the indices of each of the substitutes inside matrix (multiple occurrences are possible):

```
indices = [np.argwhere(s == matrix) for s in substitutes]
```

Then I do:

```
matrix_renumbered = copy.deepcopy(matrix)

for i, indices_per_value in enumerate(indices):
    for index in indices_per_value:
        # the substitutes are replaced just by the counter i (to be contiguous)
        matrix_renumbered[index[0], index[1]] = i
```

Expected result:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  4,  3],
   [ 1,  2,  5,  4],
   [ 3,  4,  7,  6],
   [ 4,  5,  8,  7],
   [ 2,  9, 11,  5],
   [ 9, 10, 12, 11],
   [ 5, 11, 13,  8],
   [11, 12, 14, 13],
   [15, 16, 18, 17],
   [16, 10,  9, 18],
   [17, 18,  1,  0],
   [18,  9,  2,  1]])
```

Is there a better way (e.g. using numpy) to do what the double for-loop does?

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the inner `for` loop by taking advantage of advanced indexing:

```py
for value, adv_idx in enumerate(tuple(zip(*i)) for i in indices):
    matrix_renumbered[adv_idx] = value
```

Output:

```py
array([[ 0,  1,  4,  3],
       [ 1,  2,  5,  4],
       [ 3,  4,  7,  6],
       [ 4,  5,  8,  7],
       [ 2,  9, 11,  5],
       [ 9, 10, 12, 11],
       [ 5, 11, 13,  8],
       [11, 12, 14, 13],
       [15, 16, 18, 17],
       [16, 10,  9, 18],
       [17, 18,  1,  0],
       [18,  9,  2,  1]])
```

Advanced indexing lets you pass in a list of row coordinates and a list of column coordinates, and access those elements of the array:

```py
In [1]: x = np.random.randint(0, 9, (5, 5))

In [2]: x
Out[2]:
array([[1, 2, 4, 0, 5],
       [1, 5, 7, 4, 3],
       [1, 3, 6, 8, 0],
       [6, 3, 7, 6, 3],
       [4, 3, 6, 8, 6]])

In [3]: x[[1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 0]] = 999

In [4]: x
Out[4]:
array([[  1,   2,   4,   0,   5],
       [999,   5,   7,   4,   3],
       [999,   3,   6,   8,   0],
       [999,   3,   7,   6,   3],
       [  4,   3,   6,   8,   6]])
```

Here, you're taking rows 1, 2, and 3, and columns 0, 0, and 0 with the advanced index `x[[1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 0]]`.

The only thing you need to change about your indices array is that you need to `zip()` the coordinates into two separate lists, one for row values and another for column values (instead of a sequence of `(row, col)` pairs), which is achieved by this:

```py
tuple(zip(*idx)) for idx in indices
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But, I finally implemented the [divakar 3 solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55949809/2264936), as it is also very fast. I didn't find this before. Your solution works as well, but seems to be even slower than the double for loop. I did some timing checks (although I won't guarantee that I did that the right way).