# Replacing elements in numpy array based on another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following numpy array:

```
[['CLU20']
 ['CLZ20']
 ['CLH21']]
```

I also have another array:

```
['CLU20' 'CLZ20' 'CLH21' 'CLM21' 'CLU21' 'CLZ21' 'CLH22' 'CLM22' 'CLU22']
```

I need to replace each "x" element of the first array with the element following the same "x" element in the second array.

This is the expected output

```
[['CLZ20']
 ['CLH21']
 ['CLM21']]
```

I could do this with a loop using np.where to get the index of every "x" element in the second array, but I guess there's a better way to do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fast replacement of values in a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403973/fast-replacement-of-values-in-a-numpy-array)

Comment: The keys and values of the mapping can be extracted by `keys=other_array[:-1]` and `values=other_array[1:]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
following_numpy_array = np.array([
    ['CLU20'], ['CLZ20'], ['CLH21']
]) #why not to flat this array? do you need both shapes?

another_array = np.array(['CLU20','CLZ20','CLH21','CLM21','CLU21','CLZ21','CLH22','CLM22','CLU22'])

#find the indices in `another_array` and add 1 (cose we need the follow position)
ids = np.argwhere(following_numpy_array.repeat(len(another_array), axis=1)==another_array)
ids[:,1]+=1

#update
following_numpy_array[ids[:,0], 0] = another_array[ids[:,1]]
```

Now `following_numpy_array` is:

```
array([['CLZ20'],
       ['CLH21'],
       ['CLM21']], dtype='<U5')
```

Note that if you want to update `'CLU22'` it will raise an error because there are no elements after it in `another_array`